# Avoid data.table forcing lists in j to return a column

Tags: r, data.table

Let's say that I have the following `data.table`

```
library(data.table)

set.seed(20200210)

data <- data.table(
  x = 1:3,
  y = list(
    data.table(a=4:6, b=runif(3)),
    data.table(a=7:10, b=runif(4)),
    data.table(a=11:15, b=runif(5))
  )
)

data[]
##     x            y
##  1: 1 <data.table>
##  2: 2 <data.table>
##  3: 3 <data.table>
```

When we look in the `y`'s `data.tables`, we obtain the following

```
data[, y]
##  [[1]]
##     a         b
##  1: 4 0.1019356
##  2: 5 0.5566203
##  3: 6 0.7020533
##  
##  [[2]]
##      a         b
##  1:  7 0.6080464
##  2:  8 0.4421555
##  3:  9 0.5070702
##  4: 10 0.8181770
##  
##  [[3]]
##      a         b
##  1: 11 0.8444425
##  2: 12 0.5701193
##  3: 13 0.8412783
##  4: 14 0.5692414
##  5: 15 0.8402453
```

Up until now, everything works fine. What I want to do next is to perform the operation `a+b` on each `data.table` and retrieve the result in a `list` using the `data.table` syntax. Intuitively, I would have written the following

```
data[, lapply(y, function(z){
  z[, a+b]
})]
##           V1        V2       V3
##  1: 4.101936  7.608046 11.84444
##  2: 5.556620  8.442156 12.57012
##  3: 6.702053  9.507070 13.84128
##  4: 4.101936 10.818177 14.56924
##  5: 5.556620  7.608046 15.84025
##  Warning messages:
##  1: In as.data.table.list(jval, .named = NULL) :
##    Item 1 has 3 rows but longest item has 5; recycled with remainder.
##  2: In as.data.table.list(jval, .named = NULL) :
##    Item 2 has 4 rows but longest item has 5; recycled with remainder.
```

but it won't work. What I understand is that, since my `lapply` will return a `list` and that it's defined inside `data.table[]`, it will force the return to be a `data.table` column, even if the result is of different length. For me, this behaviour is not desirable. I think it should simplify the result to a column only if the lengths match.

However, the following will actually work

```
lapply(data$y, function(z){
  z[, a+b]
})
##  [[1]]
##  [1] 4.101936 5.556620 6.702053
##  
##  [[2]]
##  [1]  7.608046  8.442156  9.507070 10.818177
##  
##  [[3]]
##  [1] 11.84444 12.57012 13.84128 14.56924 15.84025
```

but I'd rather use the `data.table` syntax if it's possible to access the `data` object.

Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is trying to convert to a single column, but the `list` elements are of different length.  We can wrap it in a `list`

```
data[, lapply(y, function(z) list(z[,  a + b]))]
```

Or if we need the same structure as in the input, wrap outside the `lapply`

```
out <- data[, list(lapply(y, function(z) z[, .(a +b)]))]
out
#           V1
#1: <data.table>
#2: <data.table>
#3: <data.table>
```

Or it can be also

```
data[, .(lapply(y, function(z) z[, a +b]))]
#                                             V1
#1:                   4.101936,5.556620,6.702053
#2:       7.608046, 8.442156, 9.507070,10.818177
#3: 11.84444,12.57012,13.84128,14.56924,15.84025
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @akrun, I was looking for the exact hybrid of your 2 proposed solutions, I want to wrap the lapply in `.()`, but not the `a+b`. Thus, I could easily assign it by reference to a new column in `data` without having my previous issue.

Comment: @J.P.LeCavalier Do you need `data[, .(lapply(y, function(z) z[, a +b]))]`

Comment: @J.P.LeCavalier I am keeping all these options in case somebody else would benefit from it.  Hope, it is okay with you.  Thank you

Comment: Yes, absolutely no problem, all 3 solutions could be helpfull for different problem.